# How to explain mobile phone rings inside microwave oven?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, wavelength, radio, microwaves

So finally tested myself and found: mobile phone rings inside microwave oven.

Microwave oven frequency is 2.5 GHz which gives wavelength of 12 centimeters. Cellular network waves are even longer. Thay should not pass through holes in microwave protection sield, which are smaller than 10 mm.

But they pass. How to explain?

---

Not working oven of course. Just phone placed incide and door closed. Signal level software shows signal degrades but not turns zero. Incoming calls cause phone ringing.

Comment: With the oven in use (dispensing power) or not?

Comment: Not working oven of course. Just phone placed incide and door closed. Signal level software shows signal degrades but not  turns zero. Incoming calls cause phone ringing.

Comment: At what frequency is your phone working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can a cellphone ring inside a microwave?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/387587/why-can-a-cellphone-ring-inside-a-microwave)

Answer (score 2):

The semi-transparent door of a microwave contains a perforated metal sheet designed to fully reflect the microwaves, but it may not fully reflect EM waves of other frequencies.

Comment: Hmmm... my Motorola Android doesn't show that behaviour.

Comment: Microwave oven frequency is 2.5 GHz which gives wavelength of 12 centimeters. Cellular waves are even longer.

Comment: Gert: In what direction is your service tower?